# ApplicationDBContext AspUsers Migration command

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core, migration, identity

I'm attempting to setup store for my IdentityServer4 Token server,
I'm following along with this [tutorial](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4)  where I encountered database migrations like so:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerMigration -c ConfigurationDbContext
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerMigration -c ApplicationDbContext
```

Apparently I'm running a different version of powershell, or the tools are messed up so I have to run my migrations using a different syntax

```
Add-Migration InitialIdentityServerPersistedGrantDbMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrantDb
Add-Migration InitialIdentityServerConfigurationDbMigration -c ConfigurationDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/ConfigurationDb
```

Theese two commands worked great however I'm still missing the third command to generate the ApplicationDbContext:

When I run I get this exception:

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.

I'm missing this table along with a few others from the database for Identity, does anyone know which Migration to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was simple.  I though Migrations were generating the Db from something that it had in code, but in actuality it seems to be constructing the database based off of the  CLR Class configuration

```
Add-Migration InitialStillDontKnowWhatThisNameIsFor -c ApplicationDbContext -o Data/Migrations/IdentityServer/PersistedGrantDb
```

I don't know what the names is for but that will generate the DB

Answer (score 1):

If you create the default ASP.NET project with authentication, you will see a migration file `00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.cs`.

So

```
dotnet ef migrations add CreateIdentitySchema -c ApplicationDbContext
```

should work.